SQL Comparison of Two Identical Tables for Differences
I have a site with over 60,000 products, and I get weekly updates from the manufacturer that I need to process so I can update my site. I have php code to load the various related tables.
I have two identical tables - one has my Old(Saved) weekly product updates from last week's app run, the other has the New weekly product updates. Both of these tables have 71 columns, so they're somewhat large. There is a column in both tables that holds the status - whether this is a new product, an existing product that has some changes (description, price, etc), or an existing product that has remained the same since last week.
I am working to find a SQL-only way to find the rows in my New table that:

are new and not in the Old table, and update the status column for those rows to contain "New"
are in both tables but the New table has updated/changed data compare to the Old table, and update the status column for those rows to "Changed"
are in both tables and are the same, and update the status column for those rows to "Same"

The objective is that ALL rows in the New table will have one of those three values in the status column after I run this elusive SQL, so I can load them into my site.
I already have the SQL to determine which products are in the Old table (last week's products run) that are NOT in this week's New table, and therefore need to be removed (no longer a current product) - so that last logical outcome is handled.
I currently have php code that goes and compares every product in the New table against the same product in the Old table to do this - there are 29 columns that I'm comparing for every row, so it takes several hours to complete, and is therefore a problem for our process.
Is there a SQL way to compare these two tables and update the status column? Even if that means running 3 separate SQL queries for each status result? I suspect there is and it would save hours, but can't work my way through this issue myself.
Update: Based on @Charlieface 's response below, I used the query suggested and changed it for my specific tables/columns/result info, and got the following:
UPDATE NewReport00 nr
LEFT JOIN LastReport00 lr ON lr.item_no = nr.item_no
SET nr.is_new_latest_run =
    CASE WHEN lr.item_no IS NULL THEN 'New'
         WHEN EXISTS (
             SELECT nr.is_family, nr.family_status
             EXCEPT
             SELECT lr.is_family, lr.family_status
         ) THEN 'Update'
         ELSE 'Same'
    END;

But this got me an error:
[2024-04-03 16:42:49] [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT lr.is_family, lr.family_status
[2024-04-03 16:42:49] ) THEN 'Update'
[2024-04-03 16:42:49] ELSE 'Sa' at line 8
[2024-04-03 16:42:49] [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT lr.is_family, lr.family_status
[2024-04-03 16:42:49] ) THEN 'Update'
[2024-04-03 16:42:49] ELSE 'Sa' at line 8

Line 8 is:  SELECT lr.is_family, lr.family_status
Not quite sure where to go from here?? @Charlieface, do you have any guidance?
After some research, it turns out that MySQL does not support EXCEPT. Left Join with Distinct is suggested, but I have yet to logic my way through this..... As I'm using MariaDB in MySQL on a Mac M2 Silicon under MAMP, I'll have to work my way through this.
Thanks!

To find changed rows is a simple join: ON t1.id = t2.id AND (t1.col1 != t2.col1 OR t1.col2 != t2.col2 OR ...) where you have to list all the feature columns that can change.

"Is there a SQL way to compare these two tables and update the status column?" Yes there is.  But with the very limited information given, no one can help you.

Check out https://docs.percona.com/percona-toolkit/pt-table-checksum.html

You can use a joined update for this.
A subquery using EXCEPT (no FROM in the subquery) will tell you if any colums have changed.
UPDATE NewTable
LEFT JOIN OldTable ot ON ot.YourPK = NewTable.YourPK
SET NewTable.Status =
    CASE WHEN ot.YourPK IS NULL THEN 'New'
         WHEN EXISTS (
             SELECT NewTable.Column1, NewTable.Column2
             EXCEPT
             SELECT ot.Column1, ot.Column2
         ) THEN 'Changed'
         ELSE 'Same'
    END;

If you are on MySQL 5.7 where EXCEPT is not supported (I sincerely hope not because it's out of support now), then you can use the following more verbose syntax.
UPDATE NewTable
LEFT JOIN OldTable ot ON ot.YourPK = NewTable.YourPK
SET NewTable.Status =
    CASE WHEN ot.YourPK IS NULL THEN 'New'
         WHEN NOT (NewTable.Column1 = OldTable.Column1 OR (NewTable.Column1 IS NULL AND OldTable.Column1 IS NULL))
           OR NOT (NewTable.Column2 = OldTable.Column2 OR (NewTable.Column2 IS NULL AND OldTable.Column2 IS NULL))
         THEN 'Changed'
         ELSE 'Same'
    END;

Obviously if the columns are not nullable then you can eliminate those branches.

Awesome - let me try this on my system. Thank you so much @Charlieface for the quick response and thorough answer!

I'm not sure why this can't be "converted" to a MYSQL-compatible version with NOT IN. As is, it won't accept more than one operand in the NOT IN SELECT,  and converting it to a version of NOT with individual comparisons won't work either. I've checked my data so I know the data will show all 3 eventualities when the SQL is correct. If anyone can point me in the right direction, based on the actual code above in the edited original post, I'd really appreciate it.

Are you using MySQL 5.7? See edits

I'm on MAMP on my Mac M2Pro Silicon, so the only option there is MySQL 5.7 - I'll look into trying to install MySQL 8 directly and working with that. Thank you very much for the answer on this!
